# How to get parent category ID in single page template

Tags: categories

How can I get parent category ID in single page template, outside of loop?

```
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->term_id;
```

The code isn't working outside loop correctly.

Comment: This should work on single posts, see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101632/73). What happens on your site? Are there other queries on that page?

Comment: I need parent category ID, it returns just category ID. Anyway, I got the solution and posed as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm solved, by using:

```
$category[0]->parent
```

Thanks anyway.